# Split sentences into separate strings where sentences start with capital letter

Tags: python, regex

Basically, I want to break up the following string into two separate strings, such that:

Input:
'LIPCIUS, A. grounded out to 3b (1-2 FBF); AMMONS advanced to second. MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).'

Output:
['LIPCIUS, A. grounded out to 3b (1-2 FBF); AMMONS advanced to second.',
'MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).']

New sentences is my case will always start with a capital letter (i.e. the name of the player). Here is my attempt at a code to do this:

```
import re

string = 'LIPCIUS, A. grounded out to 3b (1-2 FBF); AMMONS advanced to second. MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).'
x = re.findall("[A-Z].*?[\.!?]", string, re.DOTALL)
print(x)
```

My code currently outputs the following, and the first string in the list is inaccurate:

```
['LIPCIUS, A.', 'FBF); AMMONS advanced to second.', 'MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).']
it should be ['LIPCIUS, A. grounded out to 3b (1-2 FBF); AMMONS advanced to second.','MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).']
```

Comment: so you want `AMMONS advanced to second.` as another string ?

Comment: For my purposes, it is fine if that remains in the first string. I am just interested in splitting the string into two sentences, where a new sentence is identified by the sequence of characters '. A', or '. B', etc. 
In in case, just a period followed by a space, followed by a capital letter.

However, I am curious how you would achieve that as an alternative option I guess. Trying to learn as much as I can with one question!

Comment: maybe you can show us what is the expected output to make it clearer

Comment: Expected output has been included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex below should works for you, added optional [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions) of Capital letter or end `$` follow by `.` to avoid stopping at `A.` and `B.`

```
import re
string = 'LIPCIUS, A. grounded out to 3b (1-2 FBF); AMMONS advanced to second. MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).'
x = re.findall("[A-Z].*?[\.!?]\s?(?=[A-Z]|$)", string, re.DOTALL)
# ['LIPCIUS, A. grounded out to 3b (1-2 FBF); AMMONS advanced to second. ', 'MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).']
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'LIPCIUS, A. grounded out to 3b (1-2 FBF); AMMONS advanced to second. MOBERG struck out swinging (2-2 BSSFBS).'
l = re.split(r'[.][ ](?=[A-Z]+\b)', s)
print l
```

It only does not include the dot after each wanted output item but I guess it won't bother you.

Comment: Thanks! This works as well, and as you mentioned, the only difference is that the period is not included in the first string.

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<=\.) [A-Z]+\b', s)` will produce exact output with the dot

Comment: How would I modify the syntax in your last comment to account for the cases where I have a period followed by a space followed by a number, such as '. 0' or '. 3' for example?

Something like: re.split(r'(?<=\.) [A-Z]+\b | [0-9]+\b', s) ?

Comment: Actually, figured it out. This works:

re.split(r'[.][ ](?=[A-Z]+\b)|[.][ ](?=[0-9]+\b)', s)